# Function not producing the same results even when transactions are rolled back

Tags: django, database, python-2.7, rollback, django-1.8

I am testing a new feature that runs on certain models that need to be in a particular state which is product of a costly operation, so running this every time I want to test the feature is a waste of time, so I figured rolling back the transactions would do.

```
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        m = MyModel.objects.get(id=some_id)
        for e in m.element_set.filter(some_filter):
            new_feature(m, e)
        log_state(m)
        raise DatabaseError
except DatabaseError:
    log_state(m)  # this looks like the state was restored
```

This block is being used straight in a view method, with no other context variables that may be messing around with the results.

The first time everything runs as expected. I would expect the exact same behavior in the following runs, since we are rolling back the changes. However the result is completely different.

What could possibly be the reason of this? If we are reverting the database changes to the very same state it had before running the function for the first time, how are we getting a different result?

Comment: something's wrong with your indentation, `except` should be indented like `try`.

Comment: This is happening when you run tests? Can you show the specific tests you're running? Which class are you using for your tests?

Comment: @dirkgroten oh yeah fixed, that was just a typo when I pasted the code here

Comment: @dirkgroten no, these are not tests, this is happening in the dev environment

Comment: try `log_state` before running `new_feature`, just to be sure nothing else changes the state. I don't see within this code snippet what would be wrong.